# CLI command for launch of Virtual Machine using vCloud Director

Tags: python-3.x, vcloud-director-rest-api

I am trying to automate the process of VM launch using python in vCloud Director. After searching what I was able to find are REST APIs for this purpose. Can anyone please let me know if there are some CLI command available for this purpose?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

VMware doesn't offer any CLI or Python SDKs for the vCloud API. They only support Java, .NET, and PHP for their vCloud API SDKs.

I did find an unmaintained Python CLI/client that the UK government released in December 2012: https://github.com/gds-attic/vcloudtools

Given that release date it probably supports version 5.1 of the vCloud API but won't support 5.5. If you really want Python and something that's supported and you're a VMware customer you should provide that feedback to your sales/support rep so that the product managers hear it and hopefully act on it for a future release.